# How to edit HTML input value colour?

Tags: html, forms

In my input field (text), I have a text which disappears once it is clicked. How can I make this text a shade lighter by editing its colour?

Sorry, the code looks messy, I had to chop it up to show you.

Thanks!

James

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="search" size="35"    
    onclick="this.value='';"onfocus="this.select()"
    onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Job Title   
    e.g. Assistant Manager':this.value;"
    value="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager" 
    style="background-color:white; border: 
    solid 1px #6E6E6E; height: 30px; font-size:18px; 
    vertical-align:9px"/>

   <input type="text" name="searchterm" size="35" 
    style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
    height: 30px; font-size:18px; vertical-align:9px"/>

   <input type="image" src="but.tiff" alt="Submit" width="60">
</form>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe something like this (just add your style):

```
<input type="text" 
       size="35" 
       value="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager" 
       style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 30px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              vertical-align:9px;color:#bbb" 
        onfocus="if(this.value == 'Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager') {
                    this.value = '';
                    this.style.color='#000';
                 }" />

<input type="text" 
       name="searchterm" size="35" 
       style="background-color:white; 
              border: solid 1px #6E6E6E;
              height: 30px; 
              font-size:18px; 
              vertical-align:9px" />
```

UPDATE:
Since placeholder attribute is very well supported on all major browsers, there is no need to do anything manually. Its possible to achieve the same thing with this:

```
<input type="text" 
       size="35" 
       placeholder="Job Title e.g. Assistant Manager" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I used your code but when I did the input field changed shape and out of line with the other field. How do I correct this?

Comment: Like i said you just needed to add your styles. Here is it with your styles: http://jsfiddle.net/bdevic/DR4sg/4/

Comment: Ah ok thanks but I want it so the value text is a light grey and the actual text that is inputted into the field is black. And from that I changed and added font/ style color and it never changed the value text color?

Comment: I changed colors and styles in my answer. Here you see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/bdevic/DR4sg/17/

Answer (score 5):

You can add color in the style rule of your input: `color:#ccc;`

Comment: I did it but once I have clicked on the input field and the text disappears the text I type in is also this color. How can I make it so they both have different colors?

Comment: How is that used? I put it around the style part but the code just appeared all over my html page

Answer (score 4):

You can change the CSS `color` property using JavaScript in the `onclick` event handler (in the same way you change the `value` property):

`<input type="text" onclick="this.value=''; this.style.color='#000'" />`

Note that it's not the best practice to use inline JavaScript. You'd be better off giving your input an ID, and moving your JavaScript out to a `<script>` block instead:

```
document.getElementById("yourInput").onclick = function() {
    this.value = '';
    this.style.color = '#000';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `style = color:black !important;` in your input type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<input class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name" style="background-color:blue;"/>
```

You basically put all the CSS inside the style part of the input tag and it works.