# how to change the email typing color when you type it in the input field

Tags: html, css, forms

how to change the email typing color when you type it in the input field

```
 <form action="">
                
                <input type="email" name="mail" id="" placeholder="Your Email">
               
            </form>
```

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: What's the point of putting the id attribute empty?

Comment: Do you only want to change the color for an active form field? Or for a field that contains any input (but is not empty)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to edit HTML input value colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194141/how-to-edit-html-input-value-colour)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email..." />
</form>


input {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
input.typed {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.oninput = function () {
    if (input.value.length == 0) input.classList.remove("typed");
    else input.classList.add("typed");
};
```

Or if your looking for when its clicked and in focus you can use :focus like below:

```
input:focus {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```